# Nemo-preview throws out JS error

Tags: nemo, javascript

My system is Ubuntu 20.04, I download `nemo-preview` from the repository of `Linux Mint` and installed it manually. No error or warning shows in the installation. But `nemo-preview` does not function when I open `nemo`.

I run `nemo-preview` in the command line, and it shows the following information and then exit.

```
(nemo-preview-start:20719): Cjs-WARNING **: 14:03:55.707: JS ERROR: Error: Requiring NemoPreview, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'GtkSource', version '3.0' not found
@/usr/share/nemo-preview/js/ui/fallbackRenderer.js:31:7
@/usr/share/nemo-preview/js/ui/mimeHandler.js:28:7
@/usr/share/nemo-preview/js/viewers/image.js:38:7

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And the content in `/usr/share/nemo-preview/js/ui/fallbackRenderer.js:31:7` is

```
const NemoPreview = imports.gi.NemoPreview;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing `gir1.2-gtksource-3.0` and other dependent packages, I finally solved this problem.